# Add AAD authentication to a Blazor server app that use local account storage

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, blazor

I've a blazor server webapp that uses local account technique (login and password stored on database).
I need, if it is doable, extend it permitting to login also via azure active directory.
The idea is to have some user that does the login via SSO and other users using the local username and password.
I did some research whit out success.
Tnx a lot
BR

this is my configuration under Startup.cs  :

```
// Identity and Auth configuration 
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.Name = "_auth";
                    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Login";
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                    options.SlidingExpiration = false;
                });
            services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddRoleManager<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
                .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebAppContext>();
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<WebAppContext>(); // Avoid infinite loops on /Account/Login
            //
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i've updated tha request ;) tnx

Comment: Custom Auth or Identity server from the template?

Comment: Hi Brian, identity server from the template

Comment: sign in with azure ad will make your users redirect to microsoft sign page and use account in the aad tenant to sign in. Sign in with your local account require you to prepare your own sign in page. If you want both of the authentication, you have to link the user account from aad to your local account.

Comment: @TinyWang i've updated the request. I've two groups of users, some use the AAD the others use the local accounts- sorry for my english

Comment: I have a [demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73798275/15581227) here.... I'm not sure if it can help you. I integrate 2 kinds of authentication in an asp.net core mvc app.